# Namespace added automatically before public class on entity framework context.vb file after project build

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, entity-framework, mode

I am working on VB.NET project for the last two years with VS 2017 professional. Its been working fine and I have deployed the project on production without any issue. I have upgraded to VS 2019 professional recently and it's going on well but last week when I tried to update my model from database (added new stored procedure in my db) it started throwing errors. When I update the model from the database and build the project and build the project, my project name as namespace was added automatically in the `MyEntityFramework.context.vb` file.

Code  before build

```
Partial Public Class aompd2018AMSREntities
    Inherits DbContext

 ...... code
End Class
```

Code  after build

```
Namespace ProjectName
 Partial Public Class MyEntityFrameworkEntities
    Inherits DbContext

 ...... code
 End Class
End Namespace
```

Not sure what changed but I got 200+ errors. I removed the namespace but when I build again, the project keeps adding the namespace again. I end up adding using statement on all my files and manually adding namespace ref on the static files to make it work. Does anyone know what happens here?

Comment: Has a similar issue occurred in VS2017? If not, I suggest you report a problem to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).